# How can I block ad.doubleclick.net javascript (which seems to be slowing my browser down)

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, advertisements

My browser is quite slow accessing a number of sites today and they are all slowing "waiting for ad.doubleckick.net"

My goal is to stop the javascript call to prevent the slowdown. (I assume most ad tracking calls should be asynchronous, but that does not seem the be the case here. I get the "waiting..." and the page is not finished loading)

I do not think this is the ad.doubleclick virus.  I'm not having strange ads or redirects. And, I do **not**  have Ad.Doubleclick.net installed on this Windows 7 PC, nor do I have an extension with any name even similar to that. (I recognize all my Chrome Extensions).

Comment: Doubleclick is down, hence the slowdown

Answer (score 3):

Took a guess and installed [Ad Blocker Plus for Chrome](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/LxcDahggFRfo4c-hS1lo2juaOPgLzDmDgiiVD1jA3CKDDkcnYpY7mGmaAAXmYp9SXlSGKlsukQs=s141-h90-e365-rw) ( there are **two** ABP apps and the one from  from AdBlockPlus.org has 100x as many reviews and slightly higher ratings).

That seems to have fixed it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your Chrome Settings `chrome://settings/content/cookies?search=Privacy` and add whichever sites that you want to block

[image]

Comment: This is a cookie-related option, isn't it? So it won't help to block the site, if it is accessed from JavaScript, right?